# How to calculate 512 point FFT using 2048 point FFT hardware module

Tags: signal-processing, fft

I have a 2048 point FFT IP. How may I use it to calculate 512 point FFT ?

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to accomplish this, but the simplest is to replicate the input data 4 times, to obtain a signal of 2048 samples. Note that the DFT (which is what the FFT computes) can be seen as assuming the input signal being replicated infinitely. Thus, we are just providing a larger "view" of this infinitely long periodic signal.

The resulting FFT will have 512 non-zero values, with zeros in between. Each of the non-zero values will also be four times as large as the 512-point FFT would have produced, because there are four times as many input samples (that is, if the normalization is as commonly applied, with no normalization in the forward transform and 1/N normalization in the inverse transform).

Here is a proof of principle in MATLAB:

```matlab
data = randn(1,512);

ft = fft(data);         % 512-point FFT

data = repmat(data,1,4);
ft2 = fft(data);        % 2048-point FFT
ft2 = ft2(1:4:end) / 4; % 512-point FFT

assert(all(ft2==ft))
```

(Very surprising that the values were *exactly* equal, no differences due to numerical precision appeared in this case!)

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution from the correct solution provided by [Cris Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo) which does not require any rescaling is to pad the data with zeros to the required length of 2048 samples. You then get your result by reading every `2048/512 = 4` outputs (i.e. `output[0]`, `output[3]`, ... in a 0-based indexing system).

Since you mention making use of a hardware module, this could be implemented in hardware by connecting the first 512 input pins and grounding all other inputs, and reading every 4th output pin (ignoring all other output pins).

Note that this works because the FFT of the zero-padded signal is an interpolation in the frequency-domain of the original signal's FFT. In this case you do not need the interpolated values, so you can just ignore them. Here's an example computing a 4-point FFT using a 16-point module (I've reduced the size of the FFT for brievety, but kept the same ratio of 4 between the two):

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
fft(x)
ans> 10.+0.j,
     -2.+2.j,
     -2.+0.j,
     -2.-2.j

x = [1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
fft(x)
ans> 10.+0.j,  6.499-6.582j, -0.414-7.242j, -4.051-2.438j,
     -2.+2.j,  1.808+1.804j,  2.414-1.242j, -0.257-2.3395j,
     -2.+0.j, -0.257+2.339j,  2.414+1.2426j, 1.808-1.8042j,
     -2.-2.j, -4.051+2.438j, -0.414+7.2426j, 6.499+6.5822j
```

As you can see in the second output, the first column (which correspond to output 0, 3, 7 and 11) is identical to the desired output from the first, smaller-sized FFT.

Comment: This is correct too, and simpler to implement than my approach.